# Создание сервера

Tags: linux, data-mining

Стоит огромный сервер для майнинга, и аренды сервера под облачный майнинг. В основе стоят Nvidia и дистрибутив Pimp. Управление с помощью - puty. А-ля удалённо законнектился к нужному серверу и работаешь с консолью. Но если нужно например сделать апдейт для всех серверов, то тебе в ручную нужно конектиться к каждому отдельно, что довольно долго. Как можно централизовать это все дело, создав главный компьютер, из которого можно будет исполнять все? Не прошу деталей, а просто общего алгоритма, дальше я сам.

Comment: Ключевые слова -- *puppet*, *ansible*.

Comment: начиная с [0](http://rus-linux.net/lib.php?name=/MyLDP/admin/pdsh_parallel.html) и заканчивая [1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: Или хардкор expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекомендую такую вещь, как ansible.

С его помощью вы сможете выполнять как определённые команды на определённой группе серверов

```
ansible -i hosts_production miningservers -m command -a "sudo somecommand"
```

Так и описать конфигурации серверов (и положить их в гит, это всего лишь набор yml-файлов) и по мере необходимости создавать новые сервера на основе [шаблонных] конфигураций или обновлять при изменении конфигурации.

Ansible есть под большинство распространённых дистрибутивов Linux, удобство перед другими системами (chef, puppet) в том, что на сервера не нужно ставить клиента ansible.

На ru-so есть метка ansible, будут вопросы -- задавайте.